# Batch file to start a program, create a symlink, wait for it to close, and then delete the symlink

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file which executes a program, then creates a symlink, (from my usb drive to appdata), and when the program closes, the script should delete the symlink.

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8XO8.png)

I was successful in creating the program and it works perfectly, but instead of executing the application, it instead starts a `cmd` program, of the same name, *(as shown in the image)*. Whenever I try to close the said `cmd` program, the symlink gets deleted.

Please help me find a solution as to why the original application isn't starting.

Here is the code I used:

```bash
@echo off
set program="%~dp0%Stardew Valley.exe"
mklink /J "%Appdata%\StardewValley" "%~dp0%StardewValley"
echo Link Created To StarDewValley
cmd /c start /wait %program%  && cls && goto programclose
:programclose
IF EXIST "%Appdata%\StardewValley" rmdir "%Appdata%\StardewValley"
echo Link To StarDewValley Deleted
pause
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `%program%` in the place where the title goes; the `START` command expects a window title. You can leave it blank with back to back double quotes (`""`).

Try: `cmd /c start /wait "" %program% && cls && goto programclose`...

```
@echo off
set program="%~dp0%Stardew Valley.exe"
mklink /J "%Appdata%\StardewValley" "%~dp0%StardewValley"
echo Link Created To StarDewValley
cmd /c start /wait "" %program% && cls && goto programclose
:programclose
IF EXIST "%Appdata%\StardewValley" rmdir "%Appdata%\StardewValley"
echo Link To StarDewValley Deleted
pause
EXIT /B 0
```